# This Code of mine should return the frequency of the most common element

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
int max=1,m=1;
for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]==arr[i-1]){
        max++;
    }
    else{
        if(max>m){
            m=max;
            max=1;
        }
       
    }
}
if(max>m){
    m=max;
   
}

return m;
```

This is a function that I have made. This should return the number of times the most frequent element occurs. E.g if the array is `1,2,2,3,3,3` , then it should return 3. But it fails in many cases, e.g for the input `1 2 3 1 2 3 3 3`, this code fails and returns 5, which is the wrong output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting the array first and counting runs of the same number is a good idea. Your logic doesn't quite make sense through.

You need to keep track of the length of the current run, and the length of the *longest* run. Your current run should get reset when the value in the array is different to the previous value; and your longest run should be updated when the current run is longer than it.

Something like this:

```
if (arr.length==0) {
    return 0;
}
Arrays.sort(arr);
int currentRun = 1;
int longestRun = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i]==arr[i-1]){
        ++currentRun;
        if (currentRun > longestRun) {
            longestRun = currentRun;
        }
    } else {
        currentRun = 1;
    }
}

return longestRun;
```

Comment: @saka1029 Yes, it did. Now fixed.

Comment: sir, this code works but can you explain. how this is  different than mine?

Comment: Assuming `max` is the current run length, your code doesn't set it back to 1 unless it's greater than `m`.

Answer (score 3):

I can code it up for you to answer your question using the map interface.  I will check each value and if there is already a key for that value, it will increment the value by 1.  If not, then it will create the key and assign it a value of 1.

When finished, I only need to ask the map what the largest value was which is what I think you are after. And I can also return the value that was the most frequent, if you want.

Here is the tested code.  One class for the working method and then the driver class with main method

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class FindMostFrequent {

    public static Integer returnFromArrayHighestFrequency(int[] inArray) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < inArray.length; i++) {
            if (hashMap.containsKey(inArray[i])) {
                hashMap.put(inArray[i], hashMap.get(inArray[i]) + 1);
            } else {
                hashMap.put(inArray[i], 1);
            }
        }
        Integer maxValue = Collections.max(hashMap.values());

        return maxValue;
    }

}
```

And here is the driver class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] testArray = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 };

        Integer max = FindMostFrequent.returnFromArrayHighestFrequency(testArray);
        System.out.println("highest frequency is:  " + max);

    }
```

I like this technique because it allows you to easily get the minimum or another other value and its key that you want.

Comment: WJS,

Thanks.  I missed that about sort as I was looking for a method, so edited per your comment.  I did provide a solution when I first answered.  Was a coded up solution required?  I don't know because the original post did not actually state.  

I wanted to help, so gave him a technique.  I wanted to code and test, so then I did that.

Comment: You can also aggregate by `hashMap.compute(inArray[i], (k, v) -> v == null ?1 :v + 1);`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using streams, which basically uses a map to track the frequency of occurrences and grabs the highest value after sorting that map.

```
public static Long getMostFrequentCount( int ... values ) {
    return Arrays.stream(values).boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
            Collectors.counting())).values().stream().max(Long::compareTo).orElse( null );
}
```

EDIT: Made better thanks to @saka1029 's excellent suggestion

Comment: You should use `.values().stream()` instead of `.entrySet().stream()`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want...
All of the numbers you want to use is contained inside of the array a.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7};
    int count = 1, tempCount;
    int popular = a[0];
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (a.length - 1); i++) {
        temp = a[i];
        tempCount = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (temp == a[j])
                tempCount++;
        }
        if (tempCount > count) {
            popular = temp;
            count = tempCount;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(popular);
}
}
```

Comment: Your code prints `the most common element`, not `the frequency of the most common element`.

Answer (score 0):

your logic is totally correct except one line. ==> if(max>m).
In this case you are not resetting the value of max if max == m.

replace `if(max>m){` with `if(max>=m){`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `max` against `m` for each iteration.  And the use of `continue` here simplifies the logic.  Prints -1 on an empty array.

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3}; 
Arrays.sort(arr);                       
int max = 1;                            
int m = arr.length == 0 ? -1 : 1;                             
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {  
    if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {         
        max++;                          
        if (max > m) {                  
            m = max;                    
        }                               
        continue;                       
    }                                   
    max = 1;                            
}                                       
                                                                         
System.out.println(m);
```

Prints

```
4
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it.  ( I said this before but my comment was somehow deleted).